# How is the download from S3 charged on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

If someone download data from my S3 bucket into another account or into his local machine. It will be charged on my Simple Storage Service ? or the other service ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SO isn't really the place for this question but i'll answer anyway. As it's your data and your S3 bucket whenever someone accesses it, you will pay.

You could however setup a Requester Pays bucket:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RequesterPaysBuckets.html